# How to add alt tag to image from views

Tags: 7, views, media

I have created views with image gallery. Now I want to add alt tag to image how can I do it. I have not enabled alt field in content type configuration.

I want add alt tag to already existing images. Kindly provide the solution to achieve this.

Comment: is the alt tag unique for each image? or all of them will have the same alt tag?

Comment: I need unique alt@NoSssweat

Comment: just wondering why not do it through the content type config?

Comment: We can do it. But I already created content without adding alt tag.@NoSssweat

Comment: then all you would have to do is edit the content and add the tag text...

Comment: I have more than 150 content. So i am asking for alternative @NoSssweat

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to add **unique** alt text using views, unless... you use:

#### [Editable Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/editablefields)

> This module allows CCK fields to be edited on a node's display (e.g.
> at node/123), not just on the node edit pages (e.g. node/123/edit). **It
> also works within views** etc. Anywhere a 'formatter' can be selected,
> you can select editable (or click to edit).

[Video tutorial/demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jf_2e_RYS2M)

You would have to enable the alt in your content type, then you should be able to edit it in your view.

---

> I have more than 150 content. So i am asking for alternative

I take it you're looking for an easy & quick way so you don't have to edit 150 nodes one by one.

#### Another method

would be to find the alt field in your database and export the table as .csv file.

Then edit it using excel, and add your alt text here, save.

Import back in and clear the Drupal cache.